# Some error occur when boot scrapy project on python3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, twisted

```
python version=3.5.1

scrapy version=1.1.0 rc1

Twisted version =16.1.0(scrapy said Twisted version just need>=15.5)
```

I know that `scrapy 1.1.0` has totally supported Python 3.x,and I have created a project successfully. But when I try to boot the program :`scrapy crawl dmoz` I get this error:

```
2016-04-09 21:15:17 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.1.0rc1 started (bot: doub)
2016-04-09 21:15:17 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'doub', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['doub.spiders'], 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'doub.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True}
2016-04-09 21:15:18 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats', 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2016-04-09 21:15:18 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\commands\crawl.py", line 57, in run
    self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "d:\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 152, in crawl
    return self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 156, in _crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1274, in unwindGenerator
    return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "d:\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1126, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "d:\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\failure.py", line 389, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "d:\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 80, in crawl
    yield exc
builtins.ImportError: cannot import name '_win32stdio'
2016-04-09 21:15:18 [twisted] CRITICAL:
```

Comment: Can we see the code?

Answer (score 1):

我也遇见了这个问题，我是这样解决的：
pip install --upgrade scrapy

Comment: Please answer in English. Stackoverflow is a global network.

Answer (score 1):

Until now `scrapy` didn't support Python 3 on Windows, but rather on linux. I have to run `scrapy` on Ubuntu.